# How can I display images with cors problems and without server access

Tags: api, cors, endpoint

I'm fetching data (I'm working with ReactJS) from an API's endpoint. Cors is enable. 
My problem is, when I'm trying to display images (with  or ), Cors is blocking access to images.

I tried to add crossOrigin='anonymous' to  but it didn't work.

I do not have any access to the server.

I can fetch and display all the other datas.

I'm a little bit despaired, so if you have any idea to help me to display my images, it will be so great !!! :)

How I fetch my datas :

```
 fetch(myURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ items: data.items }))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          error: true
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a Proxy Server or Disable Same Origin Policy in your browser.

Here's a detailed tutorial :
https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-react-express/